# Why the read function do not require a parse argument in this case

Tags: haskell

From Graham Hutton's book 'programming in Haskell':

```
import Data.Char

getNat :: String -> IO Int
getNat prompt = do putStrLn prompt
                   xs <- getLine
                   if xs /= [] && all isDigit xs then
                     return (read xs)
                   else
                     do putStrLn "ERROR: Invalid number"
                        getNat prompt
```

There is no parse argument to the read function and yet good inputs are parsed to Int. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Haskell can deduce which instance of `Read` to use from other type.

`getNat` have type `String -> IO Int` so `return (read xs)` have to have type `IO Int`. We know that `return` have type `Monad m => a -> m a`, in our case `a` is `Int` so we can deduce that `read xs` have type `Int`.

Now we just need to find instance `Read Int` which exists.